# remove substring using regex, in Thymeleaf

Tags: regex, string, thymeleaf

I've posted this on the Thymeleaf forum, while I wait for an answer, am seeing if anyone on SO has an answer to this:

Say `testString = "abcd/xyz/removeThis"`

I want the replace to return just 'abcd' (i.e., replace /xyz/* till end of string to '')

The below doesn't work, is there an example of what might?

```
<p th:text="${#strings.contains(testString, '/xyz/')} ? 
                        ${#strings.replace(testString, '/xyz/*', '')}   :  ${testString}"></p>
```

Comment: Just tried, it's removing only '/xyz/'. not the string after it?

Comment: Try `'.*'` see what that removes.

Comment: Even though the regex appears correct, ${#strings.replace(testString, '/xyz/.*', '')} didn't work. Do I have some of mutable string replace as I'm trying to replace 'testString' in the same equation?

Answer (score 1):

You can always invoke a `String`'s method directly on a String object.

```
<span th:with="testString='abcd/xyz/removeThis'" 
      th:text="${testString.replaceFirst('/xyz/.*', '')}">
</span>
```

Result: `abcd`

Btw. I've modified your regular expression. There was missing a matcher for any character: `.`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. Since xyz is the only thing that isn't dynamic. This should match the forward slash xyz forward slash and everything after, so you can replace it: "/xyz/.*"

Comment: Hi, thanks. everything other than 'xyz' is dynamic, so I cannot use any hardcoding there, only have to remove/trim down string after 'xyz'; including 'xyz'

Comment: No it doesn't work. Even though the regex appears correct. Not sure what I'm doing wrong - ${#strings.replace(testString, '/xyz/.*', '')}